# module not found error in python while installing tar.gz file

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a virtual env and I am trying to install a private (my company's) package into it. I download the `tar.gz` file in the project repo and then I do `pip install pkg_name --find-links="."`. But every time I get this error:

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "<string>", line 36, in <module>
        File "<pip-setuptools-caller>", line 34, in <module>
        File "/private/var/folders/49/76fpmgk16_149s5r58lk33040000gq/T/pip-install-7ui62a2g/tmprint_1d674d12ea874b83b3fa7ad42797d36d/setup.py", line 2, in <module>
          import distutils.command.bdist_conda
      ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'distutils.command.bdist_conda'
```

I am using `python=3.7.4` on macOs.
Any help is really appreciated.